# I'm not able to use top level functions from my custom Kotlin library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aar

I wanted to create a kotlin library for android that contains a few top-level functions.

I've created an android library project.

I've added a few top-level functions and a few classes

```
// filename TestMethodFirst.kt
fun testMethodFirst() {}
```

```
// filename TestClass.kt
class TestClass() {}
```

I've built the library with the ./gradlew build

I've included this library to another project as an aar library

The classes from the library were resolved and imported without a problem. The top-level functions were unresolved so they couldn't be used. I've tried to add import manually but it wasn't working either. When I tried to use top-level functions from the java, as a static method execution, then it was working.

This doesn't work

```
// filename Test1.kt
fun test1() {
    testMethodFirst()
}
```

This works

```
// filename Test2.kt
fun test1() {
    TestClass()
}
```

This works

```
// filename Test3.java
class Test {
    void test() {
        TestMethodFirstKt.testMethodFirst();
    }
}
```

I've tried it with the AS 4.1 Canary 7 and with AS 3.6.2

Attachments contain the library project and the aar library

[Project](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-853187?sign=MTU5MDEwNTYwMDAwMHwxMS02NTEyNDJ8NzQtODUzMTg3fEhOYk12Si1PUmQ5Z1AxeVZnY24wRXpF%0D%0AUlhNS3I2RUQxVmFrNWFVY0habjgNCg%0D%0A&updated=1589441254948)

[Generated aar](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-853188?sign=MTU5MDEwNTYwMDAwMHwxMS02NTEyNDJ8NzQtODUzMTg4fDdmM0s4QjM5dHM5UnYxNFhwZmFaR2d1%0D%0ASjg0YUhfM1ZWOUJZTERPdlY5XzANCg%0D%0A&updated=1589441291487)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Android Studio 4.1 Canary, [this is a known bug, until Canary 9, fixed in Canary 10](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155523324). Based on [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155523324#comment3), try adding:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        excludes -= "/META-INF/*.kotlin_module"
    }
}
```

That worked for me, and a more permanent fix is slated for Canary 10.

Comment: I'm not able to use `-=` operator however this works fine 
`excludes = getExcludes().apply { remove("/META-INF/*.kotlin_module") }`

Comment: @user2875643: That feels like you're using Gradle KTS; the snippet that I posted works for a classic Groovy-based Gradle build script.

Comment: After upgrading to AGP 7.1.2, I found I had to make sure this file was not being excluded to resolve top level functions, extension functions and type aliases.

Comment: For me using `excludes` didn't help, but the `merge` did:

packagingOptions {
    merge "/META-INF/*.kotlin_module"
}